# A true statement with a false contrapositive?

Tags: derivatives, logic

Here is the statement:

> Given $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$.
>
> If the graph of $f$ is not a straight line when $x\in[a,b]$,
>
> then $\exists p,q\in(a,b)$ such that
> $$f'(p)\le \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}\le f'(q).$$

The statement is **TRUE** by *Mean Value Theorem*.

Its contrapositive:

> Given $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$.
>
> If $\forall p,q\in(a,b)$, $f'(p)>\dfrac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$ or $f'(q)<\dfrac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$,
>
> then the graph of $f$ is a straight line when $x\in[a,b]$.

Which is probably **FALSE** since $f'(p)\equiv\dfrac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}\equiv f'(q)$ for any $p,q\in(a,b)$ when the graph of $f$ is a straight line.

I am confused about which part on the above is incorrect..?

Comment: What does "$f$ is a straight line when $x \in [a,b]$" mean?

Comment: @Demophilus It means the graph of $f$ for $x\in[a,b]$.

Comment: So you just mean the graph of $f$ is a straight line? There's no need to add the $x \in [a,b]$.

Comment: Also $a \Rightarrow b$ is always true if $a$ is false. In the case of the second statement $a$ is always false, so the second statement is still true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second one isn't false, since the premise is impossible: by MVT there is an $r\in(a,b)$ with $f'(r)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$, so take $p=q=r$.

Comment: As a side note, the impossibility of the premise in the contrapositive is due to the consequent of the original claim not depending on the premise.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi good point! I suspect that the original claim should say there exist $p,q$ with $f'(p)<\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}<f'(q)$, since that is true iff $f$ is not linear.